# ListGetAt Issues when parsing CSV file

Tags: csv, coldfusion

I have a script that is reading CSV files from clients and is splitting the values into variables that will later on enter the database.

This is the error I am getting when a CSV comes in with less columns than the required minimum.

```
In function ListGetAt(list, index [, delimiters]), the value of index, 11, is not a valid as the first argument (this list has 10 elements). Valid indexes are in the range 1 through the number of elements in the list.

Expression

Invalid list index 11.
```

This is a sample of the code

```
    <cfscript>
            csvData = csvloaderCFC.loadCSVfile(csvfilename);
    </cfscript>



    <cfset i=0>



<!---  loop CSV Data ---->

<cfloop index="line" list="#csvData#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#">

<!---  Ignore 1st Row ---->
        <cfif i EQ 0>
            <cfset i++>
              <cfscript>
                continue;
            </cfscript>
         </cfif>

                       <!--- Split CSV file --->
           <cfscript>
           line = csvloaderCFC.listfix(line);
            ClientBrandID =  (listgetAt('#line#',1) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',1);
            SurveyType =  (listgetAt('#line#',2) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',2);
            Location= (listgetAt('#line#',3) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',3);
            ClientContactID =  (listgetAt('#line#',4) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',4);
            FirstName=  (listgetAt('#line#',5) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',5);
            LastName=  (listgetAt('#line#',6) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',6);
            HomePhone=  (listgetAt('#line#',7) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',7);
            WorkPhone=  (listgetAt('#line#',8) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',8);
            CellPhone=  (listgetAt('#line#',9) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',9);
            Email =  (listgetAt('#line#',10) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',10);
            BirthDate= (listgetAt('#line#',11) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',11);
            Zip= (listgetAt('#line#',12) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',12);
            Gender= (listgetAt('#line#',13) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',13);
            InquiryDate= (listgetAt('#line#',14) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',14);
            ScheduledBy= (listgetAt('#line#',15) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',15);
            ConsultServiceType= (listgetAt('#line#',16) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',16);
            ConsultDate= (listgetAt('#line#',17) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',17);
            ConsultantName= (listgetAt('#line#',18) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',18);
            ServiceType= (listgetAt('#line#',19) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',19);
            ServiceDate= (listgetAt('#line#',20) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',20);
            ServiceProviderName= (listgetAt('#line#',21) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',21);
            ServiceRevenue= (listgetAt('#line#',22) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',22);
            LeadSource= (listgetAt('#line#',23) EQ 'NULL')?'':listgetAt('#line#',23);

            </cfscript>

<!--- SQL Code begins here --->
```

I need to modify my code to be able to process smaller files regarding if they include all of the columns or not because those are valuable information as well.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [Peter's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18026854/104223). However, to answer your original question, the reason is that most CF list functions ignore empty elements. To avoid that behavior, you must use `getToken()` OR use [`listToArray()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html) with the `includeEmptyFields` attribute.

Comment: Just to be clear, whilst you can avoid the empty field functionality, that doesn't mean getToken or ListToArray can correctly handle CSV format files, because delimiters can exist in qualified fields - i.e `1,bob,"a,b,c"` - both functions result in the third item being considered `"a` instead of the `a,b,c` that a real CSV parser returns.

Comment: Thanks @Leigh and Peter Boughton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop using ListGetAt - this is not designed for the CSV file format - and instead use a proper CSV parser, such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Here's some sample code:

```
<cfscript>
    fileReader = createobject("java","java.io.FileReader");
    fileReader.init("c:\thefile.csv");
    csvReader = createObject("java","au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader");
    csvReader.init(fileReader, ",");
    ArrayData = csvReader.readAll()
</cfscript>
```

( Taken from: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1903-Parsing-CSV-Data-With-ColdFusion-s-CFHTTP-Tag.htm#comments_26608 )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will start working on it now and I will mark it as accepted after I am done.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer OpenCSV and it is the fastest in the tests I've performed. (That's my comment on Ben's blog)

If you require a ColdFusion-only solution, check out Ben's array method:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2041-UPDATE-Parsing-CSV-Data-Files-In-ColdFusion-With-csvToArray-.htm

It's not as fast as the dedicated Java class, but the end result is the same.