# Getting strange characters when using cffile to loop over a csv

Tags: csv, coldfusion, cfloop, cffile

I' am on ColdFusion 11. I' am using the following code to loop over a CSV File and output the first row in the loop.

```
<cffile action="read" file="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\file.csv" variable="csvfile">
<cfloop index="index" list="#csvfile#" delimiters="#chr(10)##chr(13)#"> 
    <cfoutput>#listgetAt('#index#',1, ',')#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

**It's outputting something strange characters. Here is the screenshot.**
[image]

**My CSV Structure**

[image]

Please help!

Comment: what does your csv file look like?

Comment: Open the csv file with Notepad.   Copy the first line to Word.  Display non-printable characters.

Comment: @MattBusche please see my updated answer.

Comment: Try using something other than `index` as your index name

Comment: `ListGetAt` ignores empty elements, so do not use it unless you are 100% certain the CSV file will never contain empty elements. There are also more robust methods for parsing CSV files, such as [OpenCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18026854/104223), etcetera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading an XLSX (MS Excel) file that has had its changed to CSV.

Notice how it starts with PK and is followed by `.xml`. This is a PK ZIP of XML, which is the native format for XLXS.

As a test, you can rename it to `.zip` and unzip it. You will see lots and lots of folders and `.xml` files

**How to correct**

You need to save as CSV, not just rename to CSV